# Fetching Data From Multiple Facebook API's then Adding Together

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

### JQuery Snippet

```
// THE FOUR URL'S TO ADD THE TOTAL SHARES
var Gal_All = "Link One";
var Gal_S_1 = "Link Two";
var Gal_S_2 = "Link Three";
var Gal_S_3 = "Link Four";

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_All,
    success: function(data) {
        showCount(data);
    }
});

var fbshares;
var fbcomments;

function showCount(responseText) {

    var json = responseText;
    fbshares = json.shares;
    fbcomments = json.comments;

    $('#fb-share-count').html(fbshares);

    if (fbcomments) {
        $('#TotalComments').html(fbcomments + ' comments');
    }

    showTotal();
}

function showTotal() {
    if (!tweets) {
        tweets = 0
    }
    if (!fbshares) {
        fbshares = 0
    }
    if (tweets !== undefined && fbshares !== undefined)
        $('#total-share-count').html(tweets + fbshares);
}
```

For fetching data from one Facebook API I have achieved however my gallery is split up into four pages `(Gal_All = all images and Gal_S_1, Gal_S_2, Gal_S_3 = categorized)`

Alike I have achieved with my Twitter counter adding for all four pages, I would like to do for Facebook so it is not showing the shares for that page, but all four of the pages.

**Please Note:** Comments fetch only needs to be from Gal_All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can request API data for multiple objects using

```
/?ids=http://example.com/1,http://example.com/2,http://example.com/3
```

Now since you want comments as well for your 4th URL, that still needs an extra API request (unless you want to fetch comments for the other three as well, just to throw them away, but that would not make much sense) – but you could use a [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) to at least get those two different API calls done with *one* single HTTP request. After all, the HTTP request is what takes most of the time in making a request to the API, so if speed is the factor you put the most emphasis on (and why wouldn’t you, users don’t like to be kept waiting), I think this is the best way to go. (Using a promise might be fine from a pure “aesthetic” point of view, but it doesn’t change the fact that multiple HTTP requests are quite slow.)

Comment: Well the other three URL's should not have any comments data as I will not be adding unique comments system to those pages, instead only Gal_All's comments system shown on all four pages

Comment: So you are only interested in the overall number of comments, the `comment_count` property (and not content of individual contents)? Well, in that case just use the `?ids=…` syntax for all four URLs, and you are done with one single request.

Comment: I need the data for all four pages for share count as for the comments, as long as I have for Gal_All it'll be good as all the others will not have any comments

Comment: Four pages but just imagine one gallery. So each page can obviously be shared but I only have the comments system enabled for the Gal_All url which will show on all pages.

Comment: Yeah, ok, alright … no need for further repetition :-) Doesn’t change the fact that you should be able to get all the data you need using one single API call, using the syntax mentioned.

Comment: I don't suppose you would be willing to show a bit more code as this is new to myself, I'm only strong with HTML/CSS, my first site is almost completed and this is just going over my head mostly to be honest with you sorry

Comment: Do I need to do something like this? `url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_All + ',https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_S_1,`...

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://example.com/1,http://example.com/2,http://example.com/3` See also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#multirequests

Comment: Okay, so I added `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.google.co.uk/,https://www.youtube.com/` and going to that URL I see the data but my script does not pick up anything. This has proven to be useful and I'm sure I'll get it working soon so I'll just go ahead and award this as answer :)

Comment: Well you’ll get a different data structure in response now from the API, when you look at the JSON response you see that it uses the URLs as “keys” on the top level now … so in that regard your script will need a little rewriting of course, that’s only natural when the format of data you request changed.

Comment: Understandable but at my experience, this has raised more questions to modify my script and get it all working... But I guess you've fully answered how to, now it's just getting it to...

Answer (score 0):

Use a promise:

```
var count = 0;

$.when(

   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_All,
       success: function(data) {
           count += data;
       }
   });
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_S_1,
       success: function(data) {
           count += data;
       }
   });
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_S_2,
       success: function(data) {
           count += data;
       }
   });
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + Gal_S_3,
       success: function(data) {
           count += data;
       }
   });

).then(function() {

  showCount();

});
```

Comment: Does the rest of my code apart from the ajax stay the same? I'm new to this method completely. it looks amazing, I'm just not 100% sure if I just replace my ajax section with your kindly provided snippet?

Comment: Does this actually go inside the ajax? I just tried replacing my ajax section with this and the first `});` dreamweaver thinks is wrong...